# DRF: Designate number of entries for queryset using prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

In my view i am trying to use prefetch_related to get data from 2 related models. The following line gives me the results i want by returning the most recent entry for all controllers in my database

```
# allNames is a list containing all the names of controllers i want to get data for 
measurements = Microcontrollers.objects.filter(name=allNames[i]).prefetch_related(Prefetch('measurements_basic',queryset=MeasurementsBasic.objects.order_by('-time_taken')))
```

However when i try to get more entries by adding [:3] at the end it still only returns one for each name in the list. When i try to do so on the prefetch query i get a slice error.

```
AssertionError at /api/CUTAQ/all/testdata/
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

My question is how i can make it so i get the amount of entries i want for each name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing is not used for getting sets of data from a queryset consecutively. If that's what you need, you better go with paginating your queryset instead.